# How to run a Window Phone 8 application in background without turning GPS on

Tags: windows-phone-8, gps

I have developed an application which needs to be running always in background.
I implemented GPS location tracking which helps application to run in background but only when GPS is on.
Following method is called when user press window button when their application is in front.

```
private void Application_RunningInBackground(object sender, RunningInBackgroundEventArgs args)
   {
            RunningInBackground = true;
            // Suspend all unnecessary processing such as UI updates
   }
```

But when GPS is turned off this method does not work or called.

Comment: pls giv more details.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just run this function when Location Service is turned off. The phone must need to take permission from the user to use it's location service.

For more information you can take a look at this link

[Reference 1 from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Audio Background agent. This agent will help you to run your service all the time in background. But running application in background will impact the battery life and will drain it soon as well.

Take your decision Good Luck